# No le demos tantas vueltas a [loops]

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Sugiero renombrar [loops](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loops) a **bucle** ya que este último es el término en español. Se usa en Mozilla Developer Network (véase [Bucles e iteración](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Bucles_e_iteraci%C3%B3n) además de otros documentos de prestigio).

Por el momento no es posible crear bucle como etiqueta pues existe [bucle-for](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bucle-for).

[loops](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loops) tiene 150 preguntas.

---

Cabe mencionar que actualmente [loops](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loops) tiene como sinónimo [for](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/for). Otra etiqueta a considerar como sinónimo de bucle es [ciclos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ciclos) la cual tiene 59 preguntas.

Comment: Me parece muy buena idea. Juntemos [tag:loops], [tag:ciclos] y hagamos que apunten a [tag:bucles].

Comment: Sí, prefiero en plural.. y quizás vaya también [tag:while] y [tag:iteraciones] en la misma bolsa

Comment: [tag:loops] no deberia tener [tag:for] como sinónimo no?

Comment: @lois6b ¿por qué no? Si es un tipo de bucle... Y con etiquetas de este estilo creo que es mejor agrupar todo en una

Comment: @Mariano porque `for` es un bucle pero no todo bucle es un `for`? Si no, añadir como sinónimos los demás bucles como `while`.

Comment: @lois6b justamente edité mi comentario anterior para sugerirlo :-) Creo que sería mejor meter todo en 1 sola. Me parece que quedaría mejor ordenado... Y realmente no hay diferencias *conceptuales* entre una pregunta que podría estar etiquetada como [tag:for] o como [tag:bucles]... O sea, sabemos la diferencia, pero a la hora de etiquetar, preferiría agruparlas

Comment: De todas formas, si bien creo que conviene todo en una única etiqueta, puedo entender que otros no lo prefieran... Y, por sobre todo, preferiría empezar a ordenar las que sí estemos de acuerdo (bucles que no sean específicamente for/while), postergando la discusión de for/while para otro momento.