# Crear etiqueta [bucles] y hacer sinónimos de esta [loops], [ciclos] e [iteraciones]

Tags: soporte, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Esta solicitud tiene como antecedente esta discusión [No le demos tantas vueltas a [loops]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3159/65) <strike>y consta de dos partes</strike>:

<strike>1. Crear etiqueta [bucles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bucles). Se requiere de un moderador ♦ pues actualmente existe [bucle-for](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bucle-for) y el sistema impide a usuarios regulares la creación de la etiqueta en cuestión.</strike>

1. Hacer

   - [bucles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bucles) ← [loops](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loops)
   - [bucles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bucles) ← [ciclos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ciclos) <strike>(ya se propuso falta votar)</strike> Hecho.
   - [bucles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bucles) ← [iteraciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iteraciones) Hecho.

   Esto requiere de un moderador ♦ pues por ser una etiqueta nueva no hay suficientes usuarios con la reputación necesaria para votar los sinónimos. Por otro lado actualmente tenemos [loops](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loops) ← [for](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/for) por lo que no es posible para un usuario regular proponer [bucles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bucles) ← [loops](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loops).

---

Para no dejar "volando" [for](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/for), favor de hacer

- [bucle-for](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bucle-for) ← [for](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/for)

Seguramente esto deberá hacerse primero para "liberar" [loops](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loops) y poder hacer esta sinónimo de [bucle](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bucle)

Comment: Agregué [tag:iteraciones], como dijo Mariano, a la misma bolsa. [tag:while] no pues tiene más preguntas y me parece que valdría la pena tenerlo por separado.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76273/discussion-between-ruben-and-lois6b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuestro estimado lois6b ♦ se hizo cargo, quedando los cambios de la siguiente forma

- [bucle-for](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bucle-for) ← [for](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/for)
- [bucles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bucles) ← [loops](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loops)
- [bucles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bucles) ← [ciclos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ciclos)
- [bucles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bucles) ← [iteraciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iteraciones)